# Python Dictionary and JSON format

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Is there any difference between Python Dictionary and JSON? They both looks the same and has key and value pairs

```
# JSON 
  "data": 
    {
    "birth_date": null,
    "birth_date_fuzzy": null 
     }

#Python Dictionary
 'data': {'birth_date': None,
  'birth_date_fuzzy': None}
```

The main difference between both the text, I could see is None and null or single and double-quotes.

Comment: One can be parsed as a JSON string and matches the JSON specs, the other is not valid JSON nor Javascript, and is text representing a Python dict literal that is also executable  as Python code?  The two should not be mixed and you should see them as entirely different things.  It just so happens there are libraries that can convert between the two representations.  serialization formats and deserialized data structures should be kept as distinct concepts.

Comment: One is a Python dictionary, the other is a string which is a serialisation of that same dictionary.

Comment: JSON is a _serialized JavaScript datastructure_, not necessarily an object or associative array (basically a set of key-value pairs) as in your example: e.g. [1,2,3,4] is valid JSON and represents a JavaScript list, 99 is valid JSON and represents an integer number. A dictionary on the other hand is the Python version of an associative array. If your JSON contains an associative array, you can deserialize it and use a Python dictionary as a suitable datastructure to store the value.

Comment: Please note python accepts double quotes as well